# nodemcu unable to retrieve's AP's MAC (BSSID)

Tags: wifi, esp8266, mac-address, nodemcu

My nodemcu lua app needs to retrieve the MAC Address (BSSID) of the Access Point the nodemcu dev kit is connected to. It is able to retrieve the SSID, but the BSSID field is 'nil'.

```
> x=wifi.sta.getapinfo()
> y=wifi.sta.getapindex()
> print(x[y].ssid)
MySSID
>print(x[y].bssid)
nil
```

What needs to be done to retrieve the MAC Address? Or is it not supported?

Comment: While the [full example in our docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifistagetapinfo) is helpful I believe the `bssid` documentation there is only partially correct. The BSSID is _not_ the same as the AP MAC address but it can be derived from it: https://arubanetworkskb.secure.force.com/pkb/articles/FAQ/How-is-the-BSSID-derived-from-the-Access-Point-ethernet-MAC-address

Comment: Btw, I get `nil` as well for my AP's BSSID.

Comment: @MarcelStör From your last comment, I think you are able to recreate the issue. Is this a known issue? Is there a solution? Is there an issue being tracked for this?

Comment: I created one: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2025

Comment: that this has been missing until now says a lot about nodeMCU's maturity (or lack thereof)

Comment: @dandavis No, not at all. It just says that no one has been missing that so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer now is that this was added to the NodeMCU dev branch on July 8th: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2026

Should be on master in the not so distant future.